# add tooltip for android action bar

Tags: android, hover, android-actionbar

i have a action bar, for the system default action "button", when i use s-pen hovered on it. it will give a "More options" tooltip and the s-pen icon change to solid circle.

how can i add the same behavior to other button on actionbar?

i tried add the hover action, but i need to implement the popup window to show the tooltip and the s-pen icon do not change from hollow circle to solid circle.

dose there exist some api to implement this feature?

see the picture.

> [image]